# Get list of all tables in CartoDB account with SQL statement?

Tags: postgresql, sql, carto

How can I get a list of all available tables in my own authenticated CartoDB account with a SQL statement?

This returns `null`:

```
SELECT table_name as t FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public';
```

Alternatively, could it be done with CartoDB.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it from unauthenticated queries. You can do it inside the dashboard though with this,

```
SELECT * FROM CDB_UserTables()
```