# Can I get a list of public tables from CartoDB without authentication?

Tags: carto

I've been running
`"SELECT cdb_usertables FROM CDB_UserTables('public')"`
over the CartoDB SQL API, but I'm getting 0 rows in return (although, notably, no authentication error).

It was my impression that callers no longer needed an API key to query public tables:
https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/issues/36

Am I doing something wrong?

Related: [Get list of all tables in CartoDB account with SQL statement?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94066/get-list-of-all-tables-in-cartodb-account-with-sql-statement)

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the tests in the https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql for CDB_UserTables(), I tried:

<strike>`SELECT 'public',CDB_UserTables('public') ORDER BY 2;`</strike>

and that still didn't work. This did though:

`SELECT CDB_UserTables('all');`

Comment: Also, for some reason doing `SELECT CDB_UserTables('private')` seems to work as well, just not `SELECT CDB_UserTables('public')`. Not sure why, since all of my tables are public by necessity, since I'm not able to make private tables.

Comment: @Kartones I believe the problem is on [line 24](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/blob/master/scripts-available/CDB_UserTables.sql): the first argument `'public'` should be `'publicuser'`